# Installing modern Deraileurs in an Old type mountain bike Frame

Tags: mountain-bike, frames, derailleur

Found my old mountainbike(steelframe) and i saw that its Rear Deraileur was worn out, was wondering would i be able to install a modern deraileur on a bike frame like this? I'd also like to ask if deraileur hangers shown in the picture with be compatible for this frame? Pls i badly need some advise about this as i want to restore this old bike

Also! Can all deraileurs be fitted to ANY bike hangers or frames? (Do they all have standard bolt size and holes)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes and yes. The "everybody else" hanger adapter does indeed fit all screw mounted derailleurs except Huret. The size, thread and location of the mounting hold are all copied from the first Campagnolo derailleurs. The only complication are direct mount derailleurs, which usually come with adapter for frames with standard mount and can be used with the claw mount adapter too.

Of course, you can still buy a modern-ish entry level derailleur with claw mount.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response!  This been bothering me for weeks, wouldn't want to waste buying the parts and have them not fitted at all

Comment: Can you explain why direct mount deraileurs would cause complications?

Comment: @kent direct mount mechs just lack the claw adapter - they're designed to be bolted to a replaceable hanger that forms part of a modern frame.  A common claw adapter will work fine for your bike, like the black pair in your fourth photo.  They're cheap too - should be under  $5 to $10 of any currency.

Comment: @Kent the complication is that you need to know what direct mount is and that you need now two adapters.

Comment: @Criggie actually direct mount means this: https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/technologies/component/details/direct-mount-rear-derailleur.html. There are three common ways to mount a rear derailleur: standard mount (which was practically everything until a couple of years ago), claw mount (which belongs to cheapest BSOs) and direct mount which is increasingly common on MTBs and may appear on road bikes too.